# Java Socket IO doesn't send to Node.js, but can connect and receive

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io

I am using [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) Java library to communication between Node.js and a Java application using socket.io.

Here is my Java implementation:

```
socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");

socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

      @Override
      public void call(Object... args) {
          System.out.println("Connected!");
      }

}).on("error", new Emitter.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        System.out.println("error");                    
    }

});

socket.connect();
```

And here is my Node.js implementation:

```
    const localsocket = require('socket.io')();

    localsocket.on('connection', () => {
        console.log('Connected!');

        localsocket.emit('error', {messsage: "error!~!"})
    });

    localsocket.on('poke', (msg) => {
        console.log("poked");
    });


    localsocket.listen(3000);
    console.log("listening on port 3000");
```

As you can see, as soon as the Java code connects, the Javascript broadcasts an `error` which the Java code receives.

The Java code outputs:

```
Connected!
error
```

And the Node.js code outputs:

```
Listening on port 3000
Connected!
```

Now, I also have a button in the Java code which executes the following:

```
if (socket.connected()) {
    System.out.println("do poke");
    socket.emit("poke", new JSONObject("{ \"message\" : \"hello\" }"));
}
```

And when I press this button, the message `do poke` appears in the Java console, but no message appears in the Node.js terminal.

The full Java code:

```
private Socket socket;
@FXML private ToggleButton button;

public Main(String com) { // constructor

    try {

        socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");

        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

              @Override
              public void call(Object... args) {
                  System.out.println("connected woo!");
              }

        }).on("error", new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                System.out.println("error");                    
            }

        });

        socket.connect();

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@FXML
public void buttonToggle() {
    if (button.isSelected()) {
        if (socket.connected()) {
            System.out.println("do poke");
            socket.emit("poke", new JSONObject("{ \"message\" : \"hello\" }"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to figure out a way that works in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

I just had to redo my Javascript code a little bit and define a framework for the server

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = app.listen(3000);
const io_local = require('socket.io')(server);

io_local.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New connection!');

    socket.on('poke', () => {
        console.log("poked");
    });

    socket.on('error', () => {
        console.log("error");
    });

    socket.emit('error', {message: "error"});
});
```

And the Java side is the same. Everything works as expected.